# Mysql foreign key errors can't fix

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, and writing a sql script from a mysql database, most of my tables work, but some won't, and the mysql error is about as nondescript as possible. It might be something to do with multiple foreign keys.

```
 create table Users (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    type enum('t1', 't2', 't3') not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    phone char(15),
    email char(30),
    username char(30),
    password char(30),
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id)
);

create table Groups (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user int not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    phone char(15),
    email char(30),
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (user) references Users(id)
);

create table Group_Members (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    group int not null,
    user int not null,
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (group) references Groups(id),
    foreign key (user) references Users(id)
);
```

Comment: What is the exact error which you are getting?

Comment: What is the actual error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` is reserved word in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-G). You have to use ` to quote reserved words in your queries.

Try this:

```
create table Users (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    type enum('t1', 't2', 't3') not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    phone char(15),
    email char(30),
    username char(30),
    password char(30),
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id)
);

create table Groups (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user int not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    phone char(15),
    email char(30),
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (user) references Users(id)
);

create table Group_Members (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    `group` int not null,
    user int not null,
    created timestamp,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (`group`) references Groups(id),
    foreign key (user) references Users(id)
);
```